# Credit Card Input Format Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a input for validating my credit card using luhn algorithm. The Luhn function does his work, and it is successfully validates my credit card numbers.

But I want to format my input type for the users as 6703 0000 0000 0000 0 (max 17 digits). I have a script for this, but the problem is when I execute the Luhn function all credit cards are invalid because it's read the credit card as 6703(SPACE)0000(SPACE)0000(SPACE)0000(SPACE)0. It's a very frustrating issue. And I can not find any workaround for this.

Do I need to change the function for formatting the digits? Or do I need to change the script for the luhn function?

Input type:

```
               <input type="text" name="credit-card-number" id="credit-card" placeholder="Enter your credit card number here" autocorrect="off" oninput="myFunction()" autocapitalize="off" maxlength="42" size="42" ng-maxlength="17" required="required" />
```

cc format:

```
 function cc_format(value) {
        var v = value.replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '')
        var matches = v.match(/\d{4,17}/g);
        var match = matches && matches[0] || ''
        var parts = []
        for (i = 0, len = match.length; i < len; i += 4) {
            parts.push(match.substring(i, i + 4))
        }
        if (parts.length) {
            return parts.join(' ')
        } else {
            return value
        }
    }

    onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('credit-card').oninput = function() {
            this.value = cc_format(this.value)
        }
    }
```

Luhn function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#credit-card-entry-form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var creditCardNumber = $('input[name="credit-card-number"]').val();

            is_luhn_valid(creditCardNumber);
        });
    });


    //validate checker
    var luhnChk = (function(arr) {
        return function(ccNum) {
            var
                len = ccNum.length,
                bit = 1,
                sum = 0,
                val;

            while (len) {
                val = parseInt(ccNum.charAt(--len), 10);
                sum += (bit ^= 1) ? arr[val] : val;
            }

            return sum && sum % 10 === 0;
        };
    }([0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9]));

    function is_luhn_valid(cardNumber) {
        if (luhnChk(cardNumber) === true) {
            $('#err').hide();
            $('#suc').show();
            document.getElementById("credit-card").style.borderColor = '#00a160';
            alert("Credit card number is valid.");
        } else {
            $('#err').show();
            $('#suc').hide();
            document.getElementById("credit-card").style.borderColor = '#FF6C60';  
            alert("Credit card number is invalid.");

        }
    }
```

Comment: So, before you pass your formatted card number to Luhn function, simply strip all the spaces from it. Like you do in your formatting function.

Comment: Would separate fields or similar not work? A hidden one for the required validation format and a visible one for display format? Display and Functional should be kept separate either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following line to remove any blank spaces in your string containing the credit card number:

```
str = creditCardNumber.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

Comment: Thx! Simple and clean solution :)